# How would you translate "scoped service" and "transient service"?

Tags: translation

I am currently writing a technical article in German which is about coding techniques and I am having a hard time translating it properly. Especially words in the context of [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

How would you translate *scoped service* and *transient service*? A *singleton* in contrast directly translates to the German word *Singleton* which totally makes sense for an educated German reader. However, *transient* and *scoped* are more difficult.

The German version of [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes) translates these terms to:

- Transient Service => Vorübergehender Service
- Scoped Service => Bereichsbezogener Service

Seems a bit bulky to me...

Comment: @planetmaker Bitte missbrauche die Kommentarfunktion nicht um (halbe) Antworten zu geben. Siehe auch: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment

Comment: "A singleton in contrast directly translates to the German word Singleton which totally makes sense for an educated German reader." - I do not claim to be (sufficiently) educated, but as a native German reader, let me say that I was totally unaware that "Singleton" is also a German word. I always knew it exclusively as an English loanword used for the programming concept for lack of a suitable German word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## In general for computer science

I learned software development in a time where every book was meticulously cleaned from English words, which made it only hard for me to learn new languages later.

Honestly, I wouldn't translate technical terms in software engineering too much. Because if you do, especially for coding techniques, your readers have a hard time to access the vast resources which are only available in English (since even most German-speaking computer scientists only write English resources).

To answer your questions, I suggest that you have a short `Begriffserklärung` at the start of your chapter.

## Service

- Service itself doesn't have to be translated with `Dienst` and especially in computer science people use it interchangeably, especially when combining it with English terms.

## Transient service

- `Transienz` and `transient` are regular German words used in a variety of technical fields (architects, electrical engineering and also computer scientists)

  - I suggest to use those terms, maybe translate it once with `vorrübergehende/flüchtige Dienste`, explain what the concept means (`Dienst wird bei jedem Aufruf neu instanziiert...`), but then use `Transienter Service` as a technical term.

## Scoped Service

- *Scoped* as in "visibility of variables to external objects" is `Sichtbarkeit` (public, private, protected), but in most modern texts I often see `Sichtbarkeit (engl. Scope)`.
- *Scoped* in "scoped service" was never translated in my opinion, because techniques like singleton, dependency injections and generics came after people stopped translating everything.

  - I suggest that you translate "scoped service" once with `bereichsspezifischer Dienst`, explain what that concept means (`Dienst wird innerhalb eines Bereichs, z.B. einer HTTP-Anfrage nur einmal instanziiert...`), but then use `Scoped Service` as a German technical term in the paper itself.

## Singelton

Together with the explanation of a Singelton `Dienst wird nur einmal zur Laufzeit einer Applikation instanziiert...` it should work well, but still give your readers access to the English resources.